# SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for . (_ssl.c:1125)

Tags: python, email, ssl-certificate, certificate, smtplib

I am trying to send an email using the python SMTP server. When I am using my personal credentials with "Gmail SMTP server and port as 587" I am able to send the message to the recipient but when I am using client credentials I am getting:

> SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'example server'. (_ssl.c:1125).

Can someone please help me on this?

Below is my code:

```py
import smtplib
import ssl
import certifi

port = 587 
smtp_server = "test@server.com"
sender = "example@sender.com"
recipient = "example@receiver.com"
sender_password = "abcdefghij"
message = "Trying to send an email"

SSL_context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.starttls(context=SSL_context)
    server.login(sender, sender_password)
    server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
```

Answer (score -1):

Give it a try as below,
go to Python folder where you downloaded python and install Install Certificates.command
and then run the code again